# Degree of Freedom twice as much as it should be?

Tags: t-test, paired-comparisons, degrees-of-freedom

I am performing paired t-test as following:

`t.test(h1$pureinf_hvar, h1$pureinf_lvar, alternative="greater", Paired=T)`

having each column of h1 (pureinf_hvar and pureinf_lvar) consisting of 43 observations each (43 subjects, data on 2 different treatments). Interestingly, the result shows a degree of freedom of 84 (or 83.925 due to Welch adjustment for the degrees of freedom).

I've performed some internet researches and found out that for 2-samples t-tests the df is typically defined as df = 2(n-1). However, for paired t-tests like mine there is just 1 group of subjects getting all treatments, so the df should be n-1, shouldn't it? Why does (Welsh-)t-test show a df of 84 (2*43-2) for paired samples intead of 42 (43-1) with my test?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In R, capitalization matters; `paired` and `Paired` are not the same thing. Also, you should use `TRUE` rather than `T` because `T` is a variable, and it's easy for code to write over it. Imagine a session in which you (or some code you ran) has innocently used `T` to hold some information. Imagine `T` got set to `0`. Now `paired=T` and `paired=TRUE` *produce different results*! In fact now the first thing actually says the same as `paired=FALSE`. That's too dangerous. Spell it out as `TRUE` (you can't accidentally overwrite `TRUE`). Being sure it's right is better than saving 3 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, are you sure that you want to conduct [Welch $t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch's_t_test)? You used parameter `Paired=T`, so I assume that you wanted to conduct $t$-test for paired samples, however `t.test` in R does *not* have such parameter, it should be `paired=T` (lowercase), so it got ignored and you conducted $t$-test for independent samples.

As about Welch $t$-tests degrees of freedom, they [are calculated differently](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48636/are-the-degrees-of-freedom-for-welchs-test-always-less-than-the-df-of-the-poole), i.e. [Welch–Satterthwaite equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation) is used. Check [Wikipedia article on $t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test), it described the *different* ways how df's are calculated for different kinds of $t$-tests. So if you conducted $t$-test for paired samples, than yes, degrees of freedom [are calculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#Dependent_t-test_for_paired_samples) as $n - 1$, where $n$ is a number of pairs.

Comment: oh ... well when I read Welch-Test I thought it would be kind of the "standard" t-test in R. But you're completely right, I want(ed) to conduct a paired t-test. As you mentioned the problem was the capitalization of "paired". Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: @martl no, it is not "standard", it is used in certain cases. If the answer was helpful you can always accept it (the "v" button) or upvote it (the up-arrow).